# Matrix summation across one axis or dimension

Tags: summation

I have a matrix $A_{w,x,y,z}$ and I want to show average across the w axis.

So I want my new matrix $X$ to be of shape (x,y,z) since we too the mean across w.

What is the proper way to write this in LaTeX notation.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{w} A_{n,x,y,z}$

or

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{w} A_{n}$

Comment: Are you conscious that you are dealing with [hypermatrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48045/why-are-matrices-ubiquitous-but-hypermatrices-rare) ; which operations have you defined on them ? Addition, but surely not multiplication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second expression makes no sense.

The first expression is confusing in this context since you seem to be using $w$ both for the name of the first variable and for the dimension on that axis.

The first would be better written with the index $w$ as the dummy variable:
$$
\sum_{w=1}^n A_{w,x,y,z}
$$
assuming that the first dimension of your matrix $A$ is $n$.